# Не выполняется анонимная функции из вызова другой

Tags: javascript

Почему в первом случае не выполняется анонимная функция, а во втором выполняется?

```
//эта часть не работает
    function testFunc(arg1) {
        return arg1
    }
    testFunc(2, (value) => {
        console.log(value + 5)
    })
    
//эта часть работает
    rl.question('username: ', (accountname) => {
        console.log("Ok")
        rl.question('password: ', (password) => {
            dologin(accountname, password);
        });
    });
```

Comment: а как в вашем представлении это должно работать?

Comment: @teran начал только писать на js. В первом случае, по аналогии со вторым написано. Почему нет вывода?

Comment: @teran Можете просто сказать, как называется такое взаимодействие с returnом функции, не могу найти информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае функция testFunc принимает только один аргумент, но вызов

```
testFunc(2, (value) => {...})
```

передает два аргумента, из-за этого анонимная функция не выполняется. Во втором случае вызывается метод question у объекта rl, который, я так понимаю, принимает два аргумента. Поэтому функция во втором случае выполняется.

Comment: Если есть какие-то вопросы, то задавайте, я готов расширить ответ.

Comment: кажется то что мне нужно, это callback и в этом роде, спасибо